# Thymeleaf - how to get value from input to "href" param in link

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an input like this

```
<input type="text" id="age" name="age">
```

and link like this

```
 <a th:href="person?age=????"> GET </a>
```

My goal is get value from input and set it into param "age" in href, because  i have a spring controller whose catch a request param. Can I do it without JavaScript, use only Thymeleaf ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Thymeleaf is a server-side templating engine, so wouldn't be able to access local parameters until they are posted to the server.

If you are trying to populate a parameter from the model (or from a previous request) with Thymeleaf, then this is the syntax;

```
<a th:href="@{person(age=${param.age)}">Link</a>
```

Comment: I am trying to populate a parameter "href" by value from input. It is possible in Thymeleaf ?

Comment: Yuu can get the original value from the controller, but if the user change it, you need to update the href by javascript.